# Database structure behind social networks [guidance]

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, post

I am working on an android app like twitter. I just want to know the logic behind it.

When it comes to mysql, would I create a new database for each user who signs up or do I have one huge database and create a table for each user who sign up? Then would each user, have a username, password, friends list and posts columns in their tables or databases?

I basically want to know if I should make a new database for each new user or a table inside an existing database..

Thanks, and sorry for the uncertainty.

Comment: a new database for each user...? O . o

Comment: Neither.  Don't create a separate object (database, table, or otherwise) for *each* member.  Have a single table for `Users` and add a new entry to that table for each user.  Have a single table for `Posts`, etc. etc.  You may want to start with familiarizing yourself with the basics of how a database works and how it should be used.

Comment: but say i had a table for posts, how would i see who posted each post? since users is in a different table?

Comment: Your Users table would have a UserID and the Posts table would have the UserID also. Then you can use the join command to link the two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're totally new to this... Here's a rough outline of how a typical app with users would be set up. I'll use some terms you'll probably want to look up to learn some of the basics of databases better.  I'll put these in double quotes and include a list at the bottom.

There would be one database for your app. This database would contain a table called 'user', with columns 'id', 'username', 'password' (you'll want to look into how to securely store passwords in a database, which is beyond the scope of this response. DO NOT JUST STORE THE PASSWORD IN PLAIN TEXT). Password is included because the application controls logging in. You do not use the MySQL users as your application users. MySQL will have probably two users - one for you and one for your application. I apologize if you already know this; you seem so new that you might not, and if that's the case it's worth mentioning because it will save you a LOT of trouble.

Each user of the app would exist as a row/entry in this table. The column 'id' is what is called a "primary key". This means that this value is different for each entry in the table, and is used to uniquely identify each user.

Then, you want to make it so that users can create posts. Each user can create multiple posts, but each post can only be created by one user, making this a "one-to-many relationship". How this is typically implemented is by creating a second table, 'post'.  Post has columns 'id', 'author', and 'content'. Again, post.id is the primary key of this table. post.author is what is called a "foreign key". This means that it references a primary key - in this case, user.id. Think of it like some sort of pointer. If you want to find the username of the person who created a post, you would look at the entry for the post in the 'post' table, and find that entry's value for author. You can use that number to find the author of the post in the user table.

For example, consider the following tables:

```
user
id username
1  awesome_user
2  more_awesome_user
3  less_awesome_user

post
id author content
1  1      I am awesome
2  3      Yes you are, awesome_user
3  2      I am more awesome
4  1      No you're not
5  2      Yes I am look at my name
6  1      having more_ in front of your name doesn't make you more awesome
```

In this case, you can tell that the 'I am awesome' post was created by the user 'awesome_user' because post.author=user.id for that post and user. To learn how to actually write queries that do this, you should google the term "joining tables".

Next, lets say you need to have users be able to like posts. A user can like many posts, and a post can be liked by many users, making this a "many-to-many" relationship. How this is typically done is by having a new table that represents this relationship.  Lets call the table 'user_likes_post'.  This table will contain the following columns: user, post.  These are both foreign keys to their corresponding table.

Now, for an example:

```
user_likes_post
user post
1    2
3    5
```

In this case,you can tell that user 'awesome_user' likes post 'Yes you are, awesome_user' written by 'less_awesome_user' because you can look up user 1 in the user table, and you can look up post 2 in the post table. Again, when writing queries, you can join tables to make this happen.

Note that user_likes_post does not have an id column. This is because, in this case, we will make the primary key (user, post) instead of (id). It is possible for the primary key to consist of multiple columns. This can only be done when no two rows have identical values for those two columns.  In other words, the following is allowed:

```
user post
1    2
1    3
2    2
```

But, this is not allowed

```
user post
1    2
1    2
```

This is useful for us because this prevents us because it will prevent double-liking. This can also be done by having an id column as a primary key, and having a "unique constraint" on (user, post), but it is highly unlikely that we will ever need to uniquely identify a like, so there's no point in having the id column, as it will just waste space. It's worth noting that foreign keys can also consist of multiple columns, so it still is possible to reference a like from another table. However, if you are considering doing this, I recommend using an id column.

I recommend you google the following terms and make sure you understand them. It may seem confusing, but pay particular attention to database normalization. Understanding some of the reasoning behind database normalization is key to designing a solid database. For example, if a single piece of data is in multiple places in your database it's a bad thing. Not only does it take up extra space, but if that data ever changes you will need to change it in each place. If you had a single table 'post' with columns 'username', 'password', 'content', and then a user wanted to change their password, you would have to find all entries in post with that username, and change all of those entries' passwords. If you missed one by accident, it could cause some serious problems. Database normalization is just a more formal definition of ways to design a database to avoid problems like that. Think of it as a 'best practices' for database design; it's ok to break the rules if you know what you're doing, but as a beginner following these rules will save you a lot of trouble.

Hopefully, this should get you on the right track for learning how to design databases. Let me know if you want clarification on any of this. Good luck!

- primary key
- foreign key
- constraint
- unique constraint
- one-to-one relationship
- one-to-many relationship
- many-to-many relationship
- joining tables
- entity relationship diagram
- database normalization

Comment: Holy craps upvoting just for the effort.

Comment: Well, it is my first post ever on this site, so I might as well make it good, haha

Comment: Besides, I've seen first hand what happens when someone who has no clue at all how one-to-many relationships work (as in, column containing pipe delimited values) designs an entire application. I've spent the past 2 years at work trying to clean up 5 years of that mess... If I can save someone else that suffering by straightening things out early on, I'm happy.

Comment: that was an amazing answer.